# Setting list order in given id sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a list which can be sorted in any order. You can detach the elements of it and by clicking on the reset button you will get all the elements again in the default order. I tried to generate the list in specific id sequence. Here is the HTML

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li data-position="1" class="ui-state-default" id='item1'>Item 1
      <a class="dummy" href="#">Detach</a>
    </li>
  <li data-position="2" class="ui-state-default" id='item2'>Item 2
      <a class="dummy" href="#">Detach</a>
    </li>
  <li data-position="3" class="ui-state-default" id='item3'>Item 3
    <a class="dummy" href="#">Detach</a>
    </li>
  <li data-position="4" class="ui-state-default" id='item4'>Item 4
     <a class="dummy" href="#">Detach</a>
    </li>
  <li data-position="5" class="ui-state-default" id='item5'>Item 5
     <a class="dummy" href="#">Detach</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<button id ="reset">reset List</button>
<button id ="new">new order</button>
```

JS code:

```
    $(function() {

         //to get the number of children for loop counter 
         count = 0; 
             //$("#sortable1").children().length;
         //array to hold the detached element 
         var array = [];  

         //function to sort the list      
        $( "#sortable1" ).sortable().disableSelection();


         // closure to detach the element and enter it in the array       
          var detachElement = (function (val) {             
          var counter = 0;
          return function (val) { 
                                count = counter;
                                alert(counter+" : "+val+" : "+count);
                                array[counter] = $(val).detach(); 
                                counter += 1;          
                           }
        })();

         //call to detach the element
         $('.dummy').on('click', function() {         
             var getID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
             var getIdStr = "#"+getID;     
             detachElement(getIdStr);
         });

         //reset all the elements again
        $('#reset').on('click', function(){                              
              for(i=0;i<=count;i++)
              {              
                  $("#sortable1").append(array[i]);
              }
              count = 0;

          /*  $("#sortable1 li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('#sortable1');
    function sort_li(a, b){
        return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;    
    }*/
            var elems = $('#sortable1').children('li').detach();

        elems.sort(function(a,b){
            var str1 = a.id;
            var str2 = b.id;
            return str1.localeCompare(str2);;
        });
        $('#sortable1').append(elems);


         });

        //custom order of the list    
        $("#new").on('click',function(){

            var elems = $('#sortable1').children('li').detach(); //1,2,3,4,5  j                        
            var newOrder = ["item3","item2","item1","item4","item5"];//3,2,1,4,5   i
            var temp = [];

            for(i=0; i<newOrder.length; i++){

                for(j=0; j<elems.length; j++)
                {
                   if (newOrder[i]===elems[j].id)
                   {
                    temp[i]=elems[j]; 
                    i++;//incrementing the outer loop
                    break;
                   }
                   else{
                        j++;                  
                   }
                 }             
            }
          $('#sortable1').append(temp);                      
        });

  });
```

Here for the new order I am getting only the first element append to the UL ("#sortable1"). please check the custom order of the list. I want all the items in the new order append to the UL.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5aaPU/329/

Comment: Not sure what the problems is here or what your asking please offer further explanation

Comment: on click to the new order button i want the list sorting according to the given ids in newOrder array. But i am getting only first matched list item saying "item3" but not the rest.@sjm

Comment: @satyanshu don't increment the for counter once more see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#new").on('click',function(){

        var elems = $('#sortable1').children('li'); //1,2,3,4,5  j  
         $('#sortable1').html();
        var newOrder = ["item3","item2","item1","item4","item5"];//3,2,1,4,5   i
        var temp = [];

        for(i=0; i<newOrder.length; i++){

            for(j=0; j<elems.length; j++)
            {
               if (elems[j].id === newOrder[i])
               {
                temp.push(elems[j]); 
                break;
               }

             }             
        }
      $('#sortable1').append(temp);                      
    });
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5aaPU/340/

Comment: Thanks man Push method is the correct one. Why the hell I incremented counter again in the loop I think I am tired :(